# Getting error when trying to compare between old and new values

Tags: apex, trigger-oldmap

I'm trying to see if the Priority value on Case changed but I get the error below and I can't figure out why.

```
        for(Case c: (List<Case>)Trigger.New) {
        if(setRecordTypeIds.contains(c.RecordTypeId)) {
            if(Trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Priority!=c.Priority) {
                do somthing....
            }
        }
    }
```

Error - Field expression not allowed for generic SObject

Comment: can you paste your complete trigger code. You might getting error in some other place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably reference Trigger.oldMap in class, not in the trigger.

Trigger.oldMap is generic which contain:
 `map<Id, sObject>`, therefore it's not familiar with specific sObject field.

You should either cast the trigger.oldMap to the relevant type:

```
map<id, Case> caseOldMap = (map<id, Case>) trigger.oldMap;
```

Or, when calling the relevant function from trigger, pass the map as parameter

```
public void myFunction(map<id, Case> oldMap)
```

From trigger call:

```
myFunction(trigger.oldMap)
```

Comment: Liron you are correct, I'm calling Trigger.oldMap in class, not in the trigger.
I used map<id, Case> caseOldMap = (map<id, Case>) trigger.oldMap; as suggested and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Type cast Trigger.old as well:

```
for(Case c: (List<Case>)Trigger.New) {
    if(setRecordTypeIds.contains(c.RecordTypeId)) {
        Case oldCase = (Case) Trigger.oldmap.get(c.id);
        if(oldCase.Priority!=c.Priority) {
            do somthing....
        }
    }
}
```